# How can I invert colors in a virtual image up the greyscale?

Tags: photo-editing

I'm not sure if the title is really appropriate as I'm not that familiar with photo editing. Here's what I mean. I have that is mostly black and white. I want to make the black parts a little brighter, and the white parts a litter darker. But there are other colors, just not as much, so is there a way that I could invert it but not as much as completely inverting it? (Hope this makes sense!)

Comment: That doesn't sound like *inverting* anything but rather adjusting levels or curves.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is essentially reducing the contrast, so any image editor with  a brightness/contrast control will do.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, although the question is not entirely clear, this is one of them in Photoshop.

Adding a *Selective Color* Adjustment Layer:

[image]

- From the *Colors* dropdown menu choose *Blacks*
- Set *Absolute* and move the black slider to the left

[image]

- From the *Colors* dropdown menu choose *Whites*
- Move the black slider to the right

[image]

<sub>*Original image from [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/photos/HIIic7I5vo0)*</sub>